# Telerik AppBuilder Using Custom Plugin

Tags: telerik, cordova-plugins, telerik-appbuilder

I have recently started some app development with Telerik's AppBuilder and am running into one thing that I'm not certain of. I added a custom plugin to my project ([Cordova Local Notifications Plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification)) which seemed to work (it shows up in my solution now under a Plugins folder), but I have no idea how to reference the scripts and such from it. According to the Telerik documentation ([Reference the Custom Plugin in index.html and config.xml](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/creating-your-project/using-plugins/using-custom-plugins/add-includes)), they say to add includes for anything with  in the plugin.xml file, yet this plugin doesn't have that.

Any ideas on how I reference their script so I can start using it? Do I just reference Plugins/cordova-plugin-local-notifications-master/www/local-notification.js file direct or something else? Here is their plugin.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification"
    version="0.8.0dev">

<name>LocalNotification</name>

<description>The purpose of the plugin is to create an platform independent javascript interface for Cordova based mobile applications to access the specific Notification API on each platform.</description>
<repo>https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git</repo>
<keywords>notification, local notification, alarm, scheduler, tile, live tiles, ios, android, windows phone 8, wp8</keywords>
<license>Apache 2.0</license>

<author>Sebastián Katzer</author>

<engines>
    <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.0.0" />
</engines>

<dependency id="org.apache.cordova.device" url="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device" />

<js-module src="www/local-notification.js" name="LocalNotification">
    <clobbers target="plugin.notification.local" />
</js-module>

<!-- ios -->
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="LocalNotification">
            <param name="ios-package" value="APPLocalNotification" onload="true" />
            <param name="onload" value="true" />
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <header-file src="src/ios/APPLocalNotification.h" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/APPLocalNotification.m" />
</platform>

<!-- android -->
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="LocalNotification">
            <param name="android-package" value="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.LocalNotification"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
        <!--
         * The alarm receiver is triggered when a scheduled alarm is fired. This class
         * reads the information in the intent and displays this information in the
         * Android notification bar. The notification uses the default notification
         * sound and it vibrates the phone.
        -->
        <receiver android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.Receiver" />

        <!--
         * This class is triggered upon reboot of the device. It needs to re-register
         * the alarms with the AlarmManager since these alarms are lost in case of
         * reboot.
         -->
        <receiver android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.Restore" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!--
         * The receiver activity is triggered when a notification is clicked by a user.
         * The activity calls the background callback and brings the launch inten
         * up to foreground.
        -->
        <activity android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ReceiverActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
    </config-file>

    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </config-file>

    <lib-file src="libs/android/android-support-v4.jar" />

    <source-file src="src/android/LocalNotification.java" target-dir="src/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/localnotification" />
    <source-file src="src/android/Receiver.java"          target-dir="src/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/localnotification" />
    <source-file src="src/android/Options.java"           target-dir="src/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/localnotification" />
    <source-file src="src/android/Restore.java"           target-dir="src/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/localnotification" />
    <source-file src="src/android/ReceiverActivity.java"  target-dir="src/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/localnotification" />
</platform>

<!-- wp8 -->
<platform name="wp8">
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="LocalNotification">
            <param name="wp-package" value="LocalNotification"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/wp8/LocalNotification.cs" />
    <source-file src="src/wp8/Options.cs" />
</platform>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any JavaScript file references are automatically inserted into your app when AppBuilder creates a build, so there is really not much you have to do aside from including the plugin. BTW, you should look for custom plugins first on the [Verified Plugins Marketplace](http://plugins.telerik.com/plugin/localnotification) - which includes instructions on including the plugin in your AppBuilder project.

Comment: Thanks for the Verified Plugins Marketplace - had no idea that existed. I tried what you suggested (just adding the plugin to the project), but in the simulator I still get a JS error. I used an example from the Telerik site (`window.plugin.notification.local.add`), but it tells me "Cannot read property 'notification' of undefined" which I assume is because I didn't reference the JS file itself on index.html. I took their example further, but get errors that `window.plugin` is null so that's probably my first roadblock. Thoughts?

Comment: The AppBuilder simulator only supports core Cordova plugins (like filesystem) and doesn't support any custom plugins. That's why you should test custom plugins and physical devices - or even better - you can now use native emulators as well.

Comment: Yep, I saw that. The issue I'm finding is their demo gives me popups saying it doesn't support it (which is good), but when I try to implement it myself I can't even get that far. If I could figure out how to get the JS file(s) referenced in my index.html page, I think I'd be all set.

Comment: Just to be clear - are you having trouble in the simulator, using the AppBuilder Companion Apps, or on a physical device? Custom plugins won't work in the simulator or Companion Apps - only when deployed to a device directly (or when used in the native emulators).

Comment: It was the simulator first, but now the emulator is causing me trouble. That'll be a separate post on here though so thanks!